# Showing that if difference of two sequence converge to zero, then both sequences must have same partial limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have two sequences ${x_n}$ and $y_n$ of real numbers, which satisfy $x_n-y_n\rightarrow 0$ and I need to show that two sequences must have same partial limits.

Here is my attempt at proof, I think it's not correct so need your help to fix it.

$x_n-y_n\rightarrow0$ can be written as $x_n\rightarrow y_n$. (Can it be written this way?)

Let $p$ be the partial limit of $x_n$, this means that $x_n$ is frequently in $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$. Since $x_n\rightarrow y_n$ this implies $y_n$ is also freqently in $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$. This is the end of proof.

I have a strong feeling that my proof is incorrect. :(

Comment: "Can it be written this way?" Not really

Comment: What do you mean by "partial limit"? Do you mean "subsequential limit"?

Comment: My definition of partial limit is "$L\in R$ is a partial limit of ${x_n}$ if given any $\delta$ neighborhood of L, ${a_n}$ is frequently in $L$. For example $-1$ and $1$ are partial limits of sequence $(-1)^n$.